# Using a Common Table Expression (CTE) in a Parent-Child Tree relationship

Tags: mysql, database, parent-child, common-table-expression, database-relations

I'm making a little webapp with a Parent/Child relationship. The problem is that the relation is recursive, is not just one level.

Let say:

Bob is father of Peter
Peter is father of Steve
Steve is father of Charles

Actually I'm doing a `RIGHT JOIN` but obviously doing that I can only access to inmmediate child.

This is that I want to achieve:

If the input is `Steve` I expect to get `[Charles]` as output.

If the input is `Peter` I expect to get `[Steve, Charles]` as output.

If the input is `Bob`   I expect to get `[Peter, Steve, Charles]` as output.

I read that CTE are perfect for this situation, because doing something like this is weird and a bit crazy (in my opinion):

```
SELECT children_user_id, ud.name, parent_user_id 
FROM
((SELECT * FROM users_parent
  ORDER BY parent_user_id, children_user_id) parents_sorted,
 (SELECT @pv := '1') initialisation)
LEFT JOIN users_data ud
    ON parents_sorted.children_user_id = ud.user_id
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(parent_user_id, @pv) > 0 AND
    @pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', children_user_id);
```

My table looks like something like:

`users_parent(parent_user_id, children_user_id)`

I'm completely new to CTE, how can I get all decendents/progeny of a give user, using CTE?

Thanks for reading and please forgive my bad English.

Comment: I clarify: that weird SQL query works, but I really want to simplify it, maybe using CTE. is a good idea? What about performance?

Comment: Are you on mysql 8 (otherwise cte is not available).?

Comment: Nope, but I'm on `10.2.12-MariaDB`, AFAIK it supports CTE.

Comment: The example given in the documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/ seems close to what you want to do. You could just add a dummy column to the anchor part eg 0 as level and increment it in the recursive part so that in the select part you can pick only those where level <> 0.

Comment: Ah! cool, I will check it up later, thank your the link!